# show pytest SyntaxWarnings

Tags: pytest

I am using Python 3.8 and there are numerous SyntaxWarnings which are remnants of code written in <3.8, and I need to quickly find all occurrences of such throughout my code so I can attempt to rectify them.

It seems that pytest is hiding these "SyntaxWarnings" from the warnings summary. Are there any flags I can use to force pytest to show them? I have tried reading the pytest documentation on warnings https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html to no avail.

Also have tried running pytest -W error::SyntaxWarning with no success.

Answer (score 0):

pytest will show them, but only when compiling pyc files (which usually only happens once) -- this is consistent with the way python works (`SyntaxWarning`s are only shown during compilation)

you can clear the pyc files with `find -name "*.pyc" -delete` for example -- this should make those warnings show up on the next run

If you're looking for a tool which can fix most of the ones introduced in 3.8, [pyupgrade](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade) can fix most of them safely and automatically: invalid escape sequences, `is` comparison to literals

disclaimer: I'm a core dev on pytest and the author of pyupgrade